# Mention people at a specified date Discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

is it possible to mention roles or people on a specified date in Discord?

Example of a command: `.date 24/01/2022 19:00 @role` and then the role will be mentioned on 24th of January at 19:00?

Comment: Hey there Afanas! Yes, this is absolutely possible. Have you tried anything? Please show a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of what you have tried so we can help you better, as Stack is not a code-writing service. Thanks!

Comment: @Bagle Thanks for the reply and I don't want to ask someone to write code instead of me. I would like to get some links or topics that I can investigate on my own. The reason for this question is that I can't find the right information about it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible.

You're going to want to utilize the datetime module (or whichever time module you prefer)

A couple things to consider:

- Unless you go with a separate db, memory will be wiped any time the
  bot is disconnected or restarted and your reminder countdown clock
  process will stop.
- If you go with a separate db, you're going to want to store the user
  ID, channel ID, and datetime object from the command (so your bot
  knows who to reply to, how to reply, and when)

I would explore a tasks.loop to check against the datetime column in the db every "x" seconds and if the current datetime == the reminder time datetime, then a message is sent to the user ID in the specified channel ID.

Comment: Thanks for your response!

Comment: No problem! If this answers your question, please accept it as an answer